# Django form data access using jquery

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

***I am working with Django forms. Django automatically renders the form for me.***

**The template rendering code is as follows:**

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" id="form1">{% csrf_token %}
    {% block content %}
       {{form.as_p}}
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="mbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Save</button>
    {% endblock %}
</form>
```

**When I view my source in the browser, the following is the output:**

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" id="form1"><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='iyBHA6drfJJ7s7eRmkKmsM6LyVpCGH1f7wQ65n78WkMpiQj8kuUUVlYrUFj06Nxh' />

    <p><label for="id_device_type">Device type:</label> <select name="device_type" required id="id_device_type">
       <option value="" selected>---------</option>
       <option value="Laptop-abcsderf-asdfghjkl12345-lenovo--">Laptop-abcsderf-asdfghjkl12345-lenovo--</option>
       <option value="Desktop-atu90667-RT56-HP--">Desktop-atu90667-RT56-HP--</option>
       </select></p>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="mbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Save</button>
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is, as soon as the user clicks on Save button, a modal will pop up. Inside the modal, the contents of the form will be displayed. Will just using the form id as a jquery selector will do? or if not then how should I iterate the form fields using each() function?

Requesting help at the earliest.

Comment: if you want to duplicate the form inside a modal, why not using `$('.modal-content').html($('#form1').html())`

Comment: But it will still let the user edit the contents right? How to make the whole form read-only? Also, how to customize the contents to be displayed in the modal? @Lemayzeur

Comment: is it like a form preview that you want to achieve? why do want to do so with form input fields?

Comment: Yea, I want to achieve a form-preview. But, I just want to display the form contents to the user, and not let him edit anything.

Comment: One last question, the form-preview is after submitting the form to the backend or before sending data to backend side?

Comment: The flow is like this: User clicks save on main form page ---->  A modal will pop-up displaying the contents that he filled/ selected ----> user clicks save changes button on modal pop-up -----> The save button of the main form (form displayed initially) will be triggered to submit the form --->The form will be submitted to the backend.   I hope this makes everything clear.

Comment: Yes, so as mentioned in comments by @KK, add read-only attributes to each input

Comment: Tell me one thing, will the code that you suggested to utilize copy the form data as well into the modal?

Comment: it will copy it as a new one with field inputs editable

Comment: It's not copying the fields. It directly displays the form unfilled inside the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
$("modalBodySelector").append($("#form1"));
```

It's better you append the complete form instead of the content to avoid duplicate ID in the HTML.
Note that the modalBodySelector is the selector for modal body

Comment: It's working but, the drop-down is still active. How should I disable it or make it read-only? Secondly, how can I remove the save button from the form displayed?

Comment: @Aishwary  Use readonly attribute to make it read-only and use hide() function to hide save button

Comment: this way is not secure since the user can simply change attribute with `inspect` tab in browser. this doesn't prevent the user to submit at all

Comment: I am just making a basic application for the purpose of understanding jQuery's working. But, in future, I will surely design keeping your point in my mind.